# How do I connect to a URL when clicking on an Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

How do I connect to a `URL` when clicking on a `ListView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there are two questions here:

**1.** How do I respond to a click in a `ListView`?

If you're using a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) override [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setSelection(int)).  Use the `position` argument to see what was clicked.

For a plain `ListView` you'll need to call [`setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) and pass in your own listener.

**2.** How do I view a URL?

The easiest way to launch a URL is to use the Built in Browser.  [You do this via an `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actcomp):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: deepthi, if webb's answer helped you solve your question, please consider accepting his answer. it sort of fuels the entire site =)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to wrap some of this in try/catch blocks as at least new URL() throws an exception upon malformed URI.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int which, long id) {
        String sUrl = "myUrl";
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));

        String res = "";

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            res += line;
        }

        rd.close();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
If what you want to do is simply to view a website in the application, then Dave Webb's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a function setOnItemClickListener() and inside it declare something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
```